# Log4j: Route logs to logger based on method-stack

Tags: java, log4j

i would like to know if it is possible to configure log4j in such a manner that all log messages that are issued from a given class will be written in an extra file, regardless wether they are issued directly by this class or indirectly (through method calls of other classes).

Let's say we have parts of our buisiness logic in class foo.bar.BL. Log4j is configured to output all logs of package foo.bar to a file. We have an interface to a customer realized in class foo.bar.interfaces.CustomerIF. To process the requests from the customer, foo.bar.interfaces.CustomerIF calls some methods from foo.bar.BL. Now we want to seperate the logs originated by a customer-request to an extra log file, including the log messages issued in foo.bar.BL.

Any ideas how we can achieve the desired behaviour?

Thanks in advance, 
takki